# need to pass the values from VF page to soql statement and fetch records

Tags: apex

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="statement" >
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLabel value="From Date"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!fromDate}"/><br/>
<apex:outputLabel value="TO Date"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!toDate}"/><br/> <br/>
<apex:commandButton value="Download" action="{!show}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Code:

```
public class statement {
    list<Account> acc; 
    public PageReference show() {
        acc = new list<Account>();
        acc= [select id,name,industry from Account where date =:fromdate]
        return acc;
    }
    public String toDate { get; set; }
    public String fromDate { get; set; }
}
```

im struck here while its asking return

Comment: You defined `show()` as a `PageReference`, however you `return List<Account>`. It's the problem.

Comment: no its not working i tried it earlier

Answer (score 2):

Try the modification

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="statement" >
  <apex:form >
    <apex:outputLabel value="From Date"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!fromDate}"/><br/>
    <apex:outputLabel value="TO Date"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!toDate}"/><br/> <br/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Download" action="{!show}"/>
  </apex:form>
  Output: {!acc}
</apex:page>
```

**Class**

```
public class statement {
    public list<Account> acc {get; private set;}
    public void show() {
        Date df = Date.ValueOf(fromdate);
        Date dt = Date.ValueOf(toDate);
        acc= [ select id,name,industry from Account where createddate >= :df AND createddate < :dt ];
    }
    public String toDate { get; set; }
    public String fromDate { get; set; }
    public statement(){
        acc = new list<Account>();
    }
}
```

**The screen output**

[image]

Comment: actually i did not create any field on account as date so i used created date as field and modified soql to ctreateddate but still getting this error                                             statement Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Datetime at line 4 column 72

Comment: Use either `date.valueof()` or `date.parse()` to parse the string to date. See the docuement for details http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse

Answer (score 0):

There are many issue, one bing that I do not see a way for you to display the return value. Are you trying to display the results?

Lets start by the 1st main issue that you have the method defined as returning a page reference but you are returning a list of accounts: it should be

```
public List<Account> show() {
        acc = new list<Account>();
        acc= [select id,name,industry from Account where date =:fromdate]
        return acc;
    }
```